# ssh into my Ubuntu 16.04 Server via Terminal

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn

I have a remote Ubuntu 16.04 server and try to ssh into it over VPN connection. 
From Windows Putty it works fine but from Ubuntu 16.04 Workstation terminal not!
Debug show me this:

```
ssh -vvv -p 33333 karl@177.177.177.177
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "177.177.177.177" port 33333
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 177.177.177.177 [177.177.177.177] port 33333.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.100 port 33333: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.100 port 33333: Connection refused
```

some Ideas what I can do?

Comment: Check that you didn't introduce a conflicting firewall rule on the client or server. Last month, that 'block everything' rule might have seemed a great idea.

Comment: But it do not block putty

Comment: Check outbound firewall rules (if any) on the client, too.

Comment: Generally, check any rules and restrictions that may apply. I once configured a (local) server so only IPs from 192.168.0.* were allowed to connect. That was the IP range I used in my local net then. Years later, a new router / DHCP server assigned IPs from a different subnet, say 192.168.20.*. It took me a while to understand why I couldn't reach that server anymore ;)

Comment: Hmm. sudo ufw allow 33333 do not the trick

Comment: If it's not firewall, then on the server confirm that sshd is running, and is listening on the correct port.